# Is there any way to get a diff of particular fields in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm working on a large software project that uses TFS for Backlog management. We're using the Scrum 2.2 template in TFS 2012. Are there any tools out there that will give diffs of particular fields (e.g. Description, Acceptance Criteria) so that I can see how these fields have changed over time and who made them ? Sort of like the 'Annotate' feature in the Source Control explorer, but for Backlog Items instead ?

Comment: Did you not see the "history" tab in the work item?

Comment: Yes, but that's not useful and it's not what I'm asking for. The history tab shows you every single version, and there's no highlighting to easily visualize differences between versions. I'm looking for highlighted differences, and juxtapositions of individual fields, and the History tab does not provide it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're looking for, then. The "all changes" view shows you a linear list of what changed, when it changed, and the value of the field before and after the change.

Comment: @DanielMann Have you ever used Beyond Compare or any other diff tool ? I want that. We have some pretty big Descriptions and Acceptance Criteria, pages of them. To find changes to two sentences between two versions is next to impossible with some of them, and I need a tool to highlight the differences, rather than showing me the complete versions of the field.

Comment: @AlexMarshall You can get the work item history programmatically using TFS API, check this blog, which made a Work Item History Visualizer using TFS API http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx

Comment: @cece thanks, but I'm already quite familiar with that api and don't want to roll my own tool because I don't have the time. That's why I'm asking if there are any existing tools

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own tool to highlight differences between revisions of a specific work item field with TFS API. You need to work with [WorkItem.Revisions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.revisions(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

There is one tool available with which you can have a reference to get started quickly, see: http://gethistory.codeplex.com/